# Handling two array of objects

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

I am having two array objects. I have to compare the first array object with second one and have to remove the object from second array if the first object has the value and the second object has not the value. If am not clear above, please review below.

```
array1={
Id:id,
Date:date
}
array2=
{
Id:id,
Date:date
}
```

if array2.Id does not consists in array1, have to remove id from the array2. i.e, I have to remove array2.id and array2.date from array2. Please help me any one.

Comment: Neither 1, nor 2 is a JavaScript array. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I need to remove only from 2.

Comment: Can you edit the question, to include the expected objects? Given the current information, it's either `delete array2.Id` or `array2 = void 0`.

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
for (key in array1){
  if (array2[key] == undefined){
      array2.splice(key, 1);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

its very simple if you have to compare same property of only two objects

```
if(array1.id != array2.id)
array2 = {}
```